# Saving double dataype in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In below spark-scala code, double data type value is storing differently. Though in table, all columns are of string type. Same result in impala as well.

Does someone knows how to make sure exact value get saved and retrieved ?

Thanks

```
val df = Seq(("one", 1324235345435.4546)).toDF("a", "b")
df.write.mode("append").insertInto("test")
spark.sql("select * from test").show(false)
```

```
+---+---------------------+
|a  |b                    |
+---+---------------------+
|one|1.3242353454354546E12|
+---+---------------------+
```

Comment: What "df.printSchema()" shows for original dataframe and received with sql?

Comment: Df shows string and double type

Answer (score 0):

Try with casting to **`Decimal type`** and then `insert into Hive` table.

```
val df = Seq(("one", 1324235345435.4546))
             .toDF("a", "b")
             .select('a,'b.cast("Decimal(36,4)"))

df.show(false)
+---+------------------+
|a  |b                 |
+---+------------------+
|one|1324235345435.4546|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for generic solution. Like if it can be possible to force all columns in df as string, without picking specific ones

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> df.select(format_number(col("b"),4)).show(false)
+----------------------+
|format_number(b, 4)   |
+----------------------+
|1,324,235,345,435.4546|
+----------------------+
```

you could use the `number_formater` function on top of column so that you it can automatically convert to string with your requirement with the precision.

hope this helps on generalizing.